# Counting equal strings in Python

Tags: python, string, comparison

I have a list of strings and some of them are equal. I need some script which would count equal strings. Ex:

I have a list with some words :

"House"
"Dream"
"Tree"
"Tree"
"House"
"Sky"
"House"

And the output should look like this:

"House" - 3
"Tree" - 2
"Dream" - 1
and so on

Comment: `sort file.txt | uniq -c` will do what you want on unix or cygwin.  Otherwise, if this is an assignment, you need to tell us what you tried already and what didn't work about it.

Comment: Do they need to be sorted in the result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [collections.Counter()](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#module-collections).  It is designed for exactly this use case:

```
>>> import collections
>>> seq = ["House", "Dream", "Tree", "Tree", "House", "Sky", "House"]
>>> for word, cnt in collections.Counter(seq).most_common():
        print repr(word), '-', cnt

'House' - 3
'Tree' - 2
'Sky' - 1
'Dream' - 1
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but note that Counter only exists in Python 2.7+

Comment: There is a Py2.5 and Py2.6 backport of *Counter* at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/

Answer (score 4):

### Solution

This is quite simple (`words` is a list of words you want to process):

```
result = {}
for word in set(words):
    result[word] = words.count(word)
```

It does not require any additional modules.

### Test

For the following `words` value:

```
words = ['House', 'Dream', 'Tree', 'Tree', 'House', 'Sky', 'House']
```

it will give you the following result:

```
>>> result
{'Dream': 1, 'House': 3, 'Sky': 1, 'Tree': 2}
```

Does it answer your question?

Comment: If you want to avoid the standard library for some reason, it would be better to replace ``words.count(word)`` with ``result.get(word, 0) + 1``. This simple change replaces an O(n) operation with an O(1) operation.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: The change maybe is simple, but more complex than you proposed. At least your proposal does not work. Did you want to say that I should replace `set(words)` with `words` and `result[word] = words.count(word)` with `result[word] = result.get(word, 0) + 1`?

Comment: ``result = {}`` and ``for word in words: result[word] = result.get(word, 0) + 1`` and if you want to put a bow-tie on it: ``for word, cnt in sorted(result.items(), reverse=True): print repr(word), '-', cnt``

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(int)
for s in strings:
    counts[s] += 1
for (k, v) in counts.items():
    print '"%s" - %d' % (k, v)
```

Comment: `defaultdict(int)` is enough. You don't need lambdas here

Answer (score 2):

I will extend Tadeck's answer to print the results.

```
for word in set(words):
  print '''"%s" - %d''' %(word, words.count(word))
```

Comment: The same comment applies as with Tadeck's solution.  Using ``words.count(word)`` is an O(n) solution.  You're much better-off using a python dictionary with its O(1) lookups.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: Same comment as below my answer: your comment is about `word in words` loop, not `word in set(words)` loop, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Below code should get you as expected

```
stringvalues = ['House', 'Home', 'House', 'House', 'Home']
for str in stringvalues:
    if( str in newdict ):
        newdict[str] = newdict[str] + 1
    else:
        newdict[str] = 1
all = newdict.items()
for k,v in all:
    print "%s-%s" % (k,v)
```